# How to define action of derivative (D) on a user-defined operator f

Tags: function-construction, calculus-and-analysis

I have a symbolic function (which is in fact an operator) `f[expr, x]` where the second argument is a local variable for `f` (kind of like how `Integrate[expr, x]` is set up).

How do I make analysis functions like `D` act on `f[expr, x]` similar to how `D` acts on `Inactive[Integrate]`:

```
D[Inactive[Integrate][Sin[p x^2], x], p]
```

> ```
> Inactive[Integrate][x^2 Cos[p x^2], x]
> ```

```
D[f[Sin[p x^2], x], p]
```

> ```
> x^2 Cos[p x^2] Derivative[1, 0][f][Sin[p x^2], x] (*Wrong*)
> ```

This output is wrong because `x^2 Cos[p x^2]` has incorrectly been pulled out of `f`.

**Edit:** It should work if `f` appears arbitrarily deep inside `expr`.  Another test case that needs to work:

```
D[a * f[Sin[p x^2], x], p]
```

with the desired result:

```
a*f[x^2*Cos[p*x^2], x] (*Desired*)
```

Comment: You can overload `D` on `f` with e.g. `f /: D[_f, x_] := someOperation[f, x]` -- do you mean something else?

Comment: I should have written `f /: D[body_f, x_] := someOperation[body, x]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jkuczm comment together with chuy's answer, I have a satisfactory solution.

Consider the following example expression (`f` is a symbolic operator introduced in OP's question):

```
expr = Cos[ f[Sin[p x^2], x] ]
```

1. When using `D`, set option `NonConstants->{f}` to prevent it from operating on `f`.  This works for any expression where `f` appears arbitrarily deep.  (jkuczm)

   ```
   D[expr, p, NonConstants -> {f}]

   (*  -D[f[Sin[p x^2], x], p, NonConstants -> {f}] Sin[f[Sin[p x^2], x]] *)
   ```
2. Then, define a rule specifying how `D` should act on `f` (chuy):

   ```
   f /: D[f[exp_, x_], p_, NonConstants -> {f}] := 
     f[D[exp, p, NonConstants -> {f}], x]
   ```

Now we have:

```
D[expr, p, NonConstants -> {f}]

(* -f[x^2 Cos[p x^2], x] Sin[f[Sin[p x^2], x]] *)
```

as desired.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is good case for [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html).  Rather than redefining `D`, you associate `f` with the desired upvalue.

```
f /: D[f[exp_, x_], p_] := f[D[exp, p], x]

D[f[Sin[p x^2], x], p]
(* f[x^2 Cos[p x^2], x] *)
```

Comment: This is nice; but if `D` doesn't directly wrap `f`, it doesn't seem to work: for example `D[a * f[Sin[p x^2], x], p]`.  Can you suggest a workaround?

Comment: @Quantum, is `f` supposed to be a linear operator, or not? It should not be too hard to modify chuy's answer to incorporate a linearity property, if so.

Comment: @QuantumDot You can use `NonConstants -> {f}` option. This will prevent `D` from using built in chain rule on expressions with head `f` and result will contain `D[f[...], ...]`,  so no matter how deep `f` is inside differentiated expression its `D`-overriding `UpValues` will be used. You'll also need to change `p_` to `p__`, so that `D` with more than two arguments (including options) will be matched.

Comment: @jkuczm `NonConstants` solved my problem.  Please post as answer and I will accept.